# Spring - Update account based on user role

Tags: spring, mapping, put, user-accounts, ambiguous

There are many types of roles in my system and they all have *DTO*-s. I don't know how to implement *UPDATE* on uniform way.

I imagined that every user should update account information sending PUT request on: `/api/account/:id`, and in *RequestBody* specific *DTO*(because they have different attributes), based on role, but that isn't possible because of ambiguous mapping.

So, what is the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is to receive JSON object in REST controller and then, based on role, map it to specific class using ObjectMapper.

*UserController*

```
@PutMapping("/account/{id}")
public ResponseEntity update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody String json) {
    //...
    userService.update(id, json);
    //...
}
```

*UserService*

```
public UserDTO update(Long id, String json) throws IOException {
    //...
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if (Role1)
        Role1DTO Role1DTO = mapper.readValue(json, Role1.class);
    //...
}
```